# MySQL Issue -- Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: mysql, sql

Need to understand error, I need to fix the error so the vehicles are shown that are in the database. WHat is boolean and why isnt it working this is a backup of the website 9 months ago . If anyone can help me please let me know

```
               </div>

<?php if(isset($_GET['dmsg']) && $_GET['dmsg']==1) { echo '<div align="center" style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">vehicles Deleted successfully..</div>';} ?>
<a href="insert-vehicles.php" style="  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 green;    color: white; float: right;  margin: 0 20px 0 0;  padding: 10px;">Insert new Vehicles</a>
            <div class="offer_area">

                <div class="offer_head row">

                    <form action="" method="get" name="form1" class="key_form">

                        <label>Keyword :(search by Make, Model, Year, Stock no)</label>

                        <input name="keyword" type="text"  value="<?php if($_GET['keyword']) {echo $_GET['keyword']; } ?>"/>

                        <input name="search" class="search" type="submit" value="search" />

                    </form>

                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br>
<br>
<table width="90%" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">IMAGE</th>
    <th scope="col">STOCK NUMBER</th>
    <th scope="col">MAKE</th>
    <th scope="col">MODEL</th>
    <th scope="col">YEAR</th>    
    <th scope="col">AUCTION DATE</th>
     <th scope="col">SALE DOCUMENT</th>
     <th scope="col">CURRENT BID PRICE</th>
     <th scope="col">BUY NOW PRICE</th>
     <th scope="col">ACTION</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
   $id=1;
   while ($GetUserQryRow = mysql_fetch_array($GetUserQryRs)) {
   ?>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><img src="<?php echo $GetUserQryRow['defaultImg'];  ?>" width="96"/> </td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $GetUserQryRow['StockNumber'];  ?> </td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $GetUserQryRow['Make']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $GetUserQryRow['Model']; ?> </td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $GetUserQryRow['Year'];  ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo date('m, d Y H:i:s A',strtotime($GetUserQryRow['LiveAuctionDate']));  ?> </td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $GetUserQryRow['SaleDocument'];  ?> </td>
    <td align="center"><?php  if(is_numeric($GetUserQryRow['CurrentBidPrice'])){ echo number_format($GetUserQryRow['CurrentBidPrice'],2); }  ?> </td> 
    <td align="center"><?php if(is_numeric($GetUserQryRow['ibuyCost'])){echo number_format($GetUserQryRow['ibuyCost'],2); } ?> </td>
    <td align="center"><a href="edit-vehicles.php?id=<?php echo $GetUserQryRow['StockNumber'];  ?>">Update</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="confirmdel('<?php echo $GetUserQryRow['StockNumber'];  ?>');">Delete</a> </td>
  </tr>
    <?php $id++; } ?>
</table>




          </div>



  <?php include('sections/footer.php'); ?>

    </div>

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you didn't post the code fully. I can't seem to find the SQL statement assigment.

Comment: Getting same issues everywhere, check this:  http://rossadamcohen.com/asa/admin/vehicles.php

Comment: Update your question with the additional code. Include vehicles.php.

Comment: it wont take all the code for vehicles.php

Comment: Well the problem appears to be with vehicles.php on line 229. So if we don't get to see the SQL query which is being executed on line 229, there is little we can do.

Comment: here click this  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IfZLtMBdsiLQGIp1jIuD5tOz2JYZCzP0Vx21SeEVA4Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sent a google docs , so u can see

Comment: ALso its happening almost everywhere its pulling data, on data driven pages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is absolutely no error handling in your code when you issue sql queries using mysql_query(). You should add error handling by checking the returned value from every mysql_query() and log / display error messages if any encountered using mysql_error().

```
$res=mysql_query(...);
if($res) {
  //do your normal stuff
}
else {
  echo mysql_error();
  //decide to stop or render futher parts of the website
}
```

Based on the mysql error message you can resolve the issues you have. My guess is, however, that the connection to the database is flawed. Wrong password, or username, or hostname.

EDIT: pls note that mysql_*() functions are slready in deprecated status and their support will be removed from php7. Convert to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your comment.